# Conflicting imports

Tags: python, import, flask, dropbox

I've installed 2 python libraries, Flask and the Dropbox SDK. Both have a module called "session". Whenever I call session, it tries calling it on both Flask and Dropbox, but then my application breaks due to Dropbox not working with that given code.

Is there anyway around this?

Comment: Use `flask.session` and `dropbox.session` (or whatever the library names are) instead of just `session`. Also, you should always do `import flask` or `import dropbox`, and _never_ `from flask import *` or `from dropbox import *`

Comment: How would you modify it? I have it like `from flask import Flask, session, redirect, url_for, render_template, request` currently.

Comment: Do `from flask import Flask, session as fsession, redirect, url_for, render_template, request`. When you need the `session` defined in Flask, call it as `fsession`. In the same way, you can give a different name to the `session` defined in Dropbox.

Comment: Posted it as an answer. Please accept it so the question doesn't show up in as unanswered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of doing this:

```
from flask import session
from dropbox import session
```

Do this:

```
from flask import session as fsession
from dropbox import session as dbsession
```

Now you can call Flask's `session` as `fsession` and Dropbox's `session` as `dbsession`.